# IntelliJ does not see sources, generated by Antlr4 (Cannot resolve symbol)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use Antlr4 with IntelliJ and Gradle and Antlr4 gradle plugin and Antlr4 IntelliJ plugin.

Unfortunately, IntelliJ does not see class names, generated by Antrl4, while Gradle tasks work fine.

In `Project Structure` I got the following chaos:

[image]

1) `generated-src\antlr\main` folder is depicted black (not red), but in different way than other sources and may be incorrect

2) a lot of red and wron source paths generated

3) generated source branch is within `excluded` group by color

4) `main` inside `generated-scr` has marking "sources root" and project name near it

5) no any root markings remain near main roots

6) "Cannot resolve symbol 'QueryByExamplesListener'" error mark inside `QueryByExampleParser.java` generated file, although `QueryByExamplesListener.java` file is right near it

Is it possible to fix all this?